# How to check for revocation list only from the CRL?

Tags: certificate-revocation, winverifytrust

I am using WinVerifyTrust to verify a file signature.

the connection to the internet is very bad so I want to check only the local cache.

The problem is that I am confused about how should I set the parameters in [WinTrustData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

regarding *fdwRevocationChecks* - the documentation is as following:

> No additional revocation checking will be done when the WTD_REVOKE_NONE flag is used in conjunction with the HTTPSPROV_ACTION value set in the pgActionID parameter of the WinVerifyTrust function. To ensure the WinVerifyTrust function does not attempt any network retrieval when verifying code signatures, WTD_CACHE_ONLY_URL_RETRIEVAL must be set in the dwProvFlags parameter.

What does it mean "No **additional** revocation checking" - in addition to what? does it make revocation checks using the CRL? if I set this field to *WTD_REVOKE_WHOLECHAIN* will it check online too?

If I set WTD_CACHE_ONLY_URL_RETRIEVAL does it enough in order to make sure that it won't attempt to get the revocation list from the internet?

**bottom line**: how do I make sure that the **there is** a CRL check, but **there isn't** any online check.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should set fdwRevocationChecks to WTD_REVOKE_NONE and *also* add the WTD_CACHE_ONLY_URL_RETRIEVAL flag to dwProvFlags. This will make sure that WinVerifyTrust will look only in the cached CRL when verifying embedded signature.